# Repository Problem in Azure DevOps, error code TFS.WebAPI.Exception: TF401027

Tags: azure, tfs

I'm running into an error code in the Pull request manager Hub in the Azure DevOps:

There was an error during the extension load: TFS.WebApi.Exception: TF401027: You need the Git 'GenericRead' permission to perform this action. Details: identity '...', scope 'repository'.

which leaves me a bit baffling since the team lead and manager is already sure that I have permission to view pull request, I could even comment and fix pull request that I was added on, but the manager hub is where it refused to show up for me.
[the permission management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIXe5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJSQC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when a user with a stakeholder license tries to create a repository

Solution: Upload the license of the user from “StakeHolder” to “Basic” or get him MSDN Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise subscription

By default stakeholders won’t have access to repos but they can try to create repository from organization settings..